# Multiple thread groups in jmeter with one hr

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have ten thread group I will run separately total duration is one hr. If I run separately it will take one hr for each thread group total 10 hrs .I want one hr total duration with run separately .

any idea on this??

I tried with one hr for each thread group run separately it will take ten hrs to complete. I need one hr to complete my script with run separately

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 10 thread groups to finish execution in sequential mode in 1 hour it means that the Thread Group duration should be 6 minutes.

1. In [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively`

   [image]
2. In [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) specify "Duration" as `{duration}`

   [image]
3. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to your Test Plan and create `duration` variable with the value of `360`.

   [image]

   in this case you will be able to change the desired duration in only one place instead of having to visit each and every Thread Group

Comment: one more doubt i applied 2000 users load for ten thread group .  I consider 2000 users report or 20000 user report??

Comment: If all thread groups are hitting same application then you should consider as 20000 report